# ECONNREFUSED error with node.js that does not occur in other clients

Tags: http, node.js

I'm making an `http` request with the `node.js` client, and I get an `ECONNREFUSED` error.  When I make what appears to be the same request with my browser or `curl(1)`, it works just fine

Here's the node request:

```
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/explorers/1.0/agegroup',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});

req.end();
```

And it gives me the error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

But when I make the same request with a different client (`curl` in this case):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/explorers/1.0/agegroup
{... response JSON ...}
```

Other notes:

- I've tried changing the host to www.google.com and the port to 80, and node makes the connection successfully
- I've tried changing the port of the server, and I can still make requests with all clients but node.js (which still gets `ECONNREFUSED`)
- The server to which I'm connecting is the [CherryPy WSGI Server](https://github.com/od-eon/cherrypy-wsgiserver/blob/master/wsgiserver/__init__.py).  When I try connecting to a `node` server at localhost:8080, it works fine, which would make me think it's the server's problem, except other clients work with the CherryPy server.
- I've tried using the same headers that my browser is using, but that doesn't work, and it seems like the problem is at the TCP level anyway, so HTTP headers shouldn't be an issue.

What's wrong with my `node` request?

Comment: I am getting this same behaviour - it just started exhibiting, inexplicably. If I figure it out, I'll try to post some info.

Comment: same for me, i have the problem with the phantomjs webserver, which is supposedly using mongoose.

Comment: After searching for hours, this thread has the answer(s) for my ECONNREFUSED problem with node.js. aaronstacy's and steveorevo's answers are what helped me, which is to replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in the gruntfile.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess sometimes you just need to step away from the problem...

I found a solution, but it doesn't seem to answer the question, and I don't really like the it.

I changed the CherryPy server configuration to serve at `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, and the `node` client started working.

Comment: interesting ... i have used localhost to connect to redis as well as mysql, but never faced the problem .... were you trying the curl from the same server? (wondering if the hosts file could be having a problem)

Comment: yes, the curl command and node script were exactly as in the question, both hitting localhost:8080

Answer (score 19):

I disagree with Soman's disagreement.

I've been pulling my hair out on this one, but yes, sure enough nodejs v0.10.24 and v0.10.25 refuse to connect to a PHP 5.4 development server (PHP's command line server) when invoked as:

```
php -S localhost:8088
```

The browser, curl, everything else connects just fine. Yet, sure enough, changing the binding address to be:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8088
```

And nodejs' using xmlrpc connects just fine. This occurred on a Mac OS X 10.9.1. Very odd.

Comment: node.js is not honoring the system hosts file when doing dns resolution

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried any possible combination on Node side (localhost, 127.0.0.1, LAN IP, domain name using host file, etc.) but no luck. Changed my run configuration in PHPStorm and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: happened with me too !

Comment: You are a hero, saint, and a scholar. Thank you!

Comment: If this doesn't work - don't despair - try myst552's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716912/1290746

Answer (score 7):

I just faced the same problem.

Note that Windows 7 by default doesn't include an entry for localhost in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` ([wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#File%20content))

Adding the entry for localhost has no effect with Node.js (0.10.25) as it apparently skips the hosts file completely.

Use 127.0.0.1 as local address instead, this will works what ever is in your hosts file.

Comment: That was the case for me, 1h of raging before realize I've changed the localhost in my hosts.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I was able to resolve it by replacing the localhost or 127.0.0.1 by my system's ip address(use ifconfig for the ip address).

Comment: Thank God for Stackoverflow.  I wouldn't have thought to try it - but this was the solution.
(Neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1 worked for me either)

Comment: worked like a charm. I spent three days on this stupid issue.

Answer (score 0):

$ ifconfig

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ....  
inet addr:**172.17.0.1**  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
.....

var dbSettings = {
host: '**172.17.0.1**',
user: 'root',
password: '.......',
database: '.......',
port: '3306'
};

docker ip -> host

Answer (score 0):

what worked best for me was using the same port as my xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by check my `mysqlBench`
I found difficult to connect to my local `mysql`

and I tried:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

It works straight way

Answer (score -1):

I exactly faced the same issue where I was accessing a third party url. I tried using dns (subdomain.domain.com) and ip (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) both but it did not work.

After some struggle, later I realized that this was a problem at server (subdomain.domain.com) end which was not responsive and gone down.

I disagree this is a problem with localhost / 127.0.0.1 (or domain name vs IP address). ( In above case, it's surely a case of incorrect host mapping)

Comment: hm, i don't think i follow -- the dns mapping usually happens in libraries below the node.js/curl level (see gethostbyname(3)). so in the question it wasn't a host mapping issue...