# node.js request module giving error for http call [Error: Invalid protocol: null]

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

I am using request module for node.js to make HTTP GET call to an api having address like: `http://x.x.xxx.xx:8000/names` but the call is returning an error `[Error: Invalid protocol: null]`.

My api call looks like this:

```
request.get({
    uri: 'http://x.x.xxx.xx:8000/names'
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err == null){
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }});
```

Note: I have used proxies for npm through "npm config set proxy" and "npm config set https proxy" . Removing them is also not solving the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your proxy config please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this, works perfectly fine, I'll say that the problem is in your proxy config.

```
request.get({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/names'
}, function(err, res, body){

});
```

Try this:

```
npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@host:port
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the request.get, you must first specify the url as a string, followed by a dictionary with options, if you want to pass an option. The error is likely due to confusion that you're passing in a dictionary. Either try using `request()` with a dictionary parameter or `request.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/')`

Docs for reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#convenience-methods

Comment: It is not that, that request is well formed.

Answer (score 0):

I had my `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable incorrectly set

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a PHP development server please [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643965/econnrefused-error-with-node-js-that-does-not-occur-in-other-clients/21375340#21375340) for solution