# How to send http post call from node server?

Tags: node.js, post

I have trying to send post call on `https://api-mean.herokuapp.com/api/contacts` with following data:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test@xxxx.in",
    "phone": "989898xxxx"
}
```

But not get any response.
I have also tried it with postman it working fine. I have get response in postman.

I am using following nodejs code:

```
        var postData = querystring.stringify({
            "name": "Test",
            "email": "test@xxxx.in",
            "phone": "989898xxxx"
        });

        var options = {
            hostname: 'https://api-mean.herokuapp.com',
            path: '/api/contacts',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            var output = '';
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                output += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', function () {
                var obj = JSON.parse(output.trim());
                console.log('working = ', obj);
                resolve(obj);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });

        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
```

Am I something missing?

How to send http post call from node server?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module to make things easier.

```
   var request=require('request');

   var json = {
     "name": "Test",
     "email": "test@xxxx.in",
     "phone": "989898xxxx"
   };

   var options = {
     url: 'https://api-mean.herokuapp.com/api/contacts',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     json: json
   };

   request(options, function(err, res, body) {
     if (res && (res.statusCode === 200 || res.statusCode === 201)) {
       console.log(body);
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thank for reply.


working but getting error : **[Error: Invalid protocol: null]**

Comment: there is some proxy issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964935/node-js-request-module-giving-error-for-http-call-error-invalid-protocol-null

Comment: try to set your npm config proxy

Comment: Yes some API returns `200`,  `201`  for success result

Comment: change the condition with res.statusCode===201

Answer (score 0):

For sending HTTP-POST call from nodejs, you might need to use the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Sample:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    url: "some site",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        // header info - in case of authentication enabled
    },
    json:{
        // body goes here
    }, function(err, res, body){
        if(!err){
            // do your thing
        }else{
            // handle error
        }
    });
```