# request not work, Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:?

Tags: node.js, request

I am new to node.js, I use request send the post request.but I got a error!

```
     request({
         method: 'POST',
         url: config.api + '/index',
         body: {
         name: "name"
        },
        json: true
      })

        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^

         Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:
```

Comment: The URL is missing the `http://` prefix? What is the value of `config.api`?

Comment: Thank you, I forget the **http://**. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write this: It work fine, you can modify it like this.

```
     request({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' + '/index',
           body: {
           name: "name"
          },
          json: true
          })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect: follow the instructions on the [NPM module page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a PHP Development Server please refer to this thread for the solution. 
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643965/econnrefused-error-with-node-js-that-does-not-occur-in-other-clients/21375340#21375340)

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue on `Win10` after a system update. It was caused by the system proxy settings.

```
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
```

Change the above environment settings to

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

done the job for me.

Btw, if you use `git-bash`, you can also check the `git` config.

```
$git config --list
...
http.sslverify=false
http.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
https.proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
...
```