# Can't connect to MySQL from NodeJs but it works from server console

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a NodeJs/express/Typescript application, that runs on an ubuntu 20.04 server via NGINX. The apps run on a subdomain api.mydomaon.com on port 4040.

The same server also hosts my MySQL database 'myshop' on default port 3306.

I have created a mysql user myuser@localhost with CRUD rights for the DB 'myshop'.

When i want to access the db with the user via console `mysql -u myuser -h localhost -port=3306 -p` i get a password prompt and can connect.

When i use the same credentials in my NodeJs app i always get an error from NodeJs: `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306`.

here is my express connection code:

```
const connectDetails = {
      host: process.env.DBHOST,
      user: process.env.DBUSER,
      password: process.env.DBPWD,
      database: "myshop",
      port: parseInt(process.env.DBPORT as string),
      debug: false,
    };

    console.log(connectDetails); // <-- this correctly shows me the settings. see below.

    this._connection = createPool(connectDetails);
```

When i start up the app, it shows me the used settings of my connection attempt from the console.log above.

```
{
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypassword',
  database: 'myshop',
  port: 3306,
  debug: true
}
```

At startup i don't get an error.

That error appears the moment i try to use `this._connection` to execute a query on my DB.
like: `this._connection.execute(query, values, (err, results) => { ... }`

I tried to restart the DB, deleted and recreated the user, provided a socket path and red the web for hours.

I'd be very thankful for hints that point at a working solution

Comment: Did you check, which hosts granted to login? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost?rq=2 and one more link about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643965/econnrefused-error-with-node-js-that-does-not-occur-in-other-clients

Comment: @FriendlyDragon many many thanks! the plugin was the missing link!
the two posts you linked set me on the correct tracks. gonna leave the solution here in an answer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @FriendlyDragon i was able to track it down.

I had to adjust two things:

**1. localhost to 127.0.0.1**

somehow NodeJs wants the IP instead of the string 'localhost'.
see here: [ECONNREFUSED error with node.js that does not occur in other clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643965/econnrefused-error-with-node-js-that-does-not-occur-in-other-clients)

**2. change mysql auth plugin**

apparently MySQL 8 is using a new default plugin for authentication: `caching_sha2_password` instead of `mysql_native_password`.

The latest node-mysql2 package version does not yet support that new default plugin.
see this post:
[Node.js can't authenticate to MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0)

there are two solutions:

- Update node-mysql2 package

for if you are from the future where they have fixed that issue.
see here: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1248#issuecomment-1637257814

- Change the auth plugin used for your mysql user

temporaly until you can get a node-mysql2 package version that can deal with the new auth plugin

`ALTER USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';`

Comment: I should mention that this is not a NodeJS issue but whatever library you are using as a connector...so "upgrading node.js" would never fix this problem

Comment: @delis you are right. It is about the node-mysl2 package that does not yet support the new plugin. So not NodeJs needs an update but that package. I gonna change my answer. many thanks for the right hint!

Comment: Also, your `ECONNREFUSED` issue is more related to dns lookup (it's attempting to use ipv6 resolution for localhost (::1) as against ipv4 (127.0.0.1)) see: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702#issuecomment-958157082

Comment: I saw in the error already that it was referring to IPv6. That is why i had to change 2 things to make it work. Like described in my updated version of my answer. Changing 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1 was also needed to fix my problem. Thank you for taking a look at my problem